# vb.net - client http.response - waiting for user to save file - Internet Explorer

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, client-side

Afternoon everyone,

I have a vb.net application that takes multiple files, condenses them into a zip file and then sends that file to the client via a http.response.outputstream.write, then deletes the temporary files so the server doesn't get bogged down with junk (this is all done on demand depending on what files they requested).  Everything works great in Chrome.

However in IE, when the first flush hits, it asks what to do with the file.  This does not halt the code so it keep going on it's merry way, sending buffered chunks (which it seems IE doesn't receive because it is waiting on user input), closing the response and subsequently deleting the file.

Is there a way to send a file via an http response that doesn't jam up like this in vb.net?  Right now I am just on my test machine so no clients affected yet (glad I decided to test multiple browsers....)

Thanks for any help!!

update - code I am using is pretty much copied from here [link to MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406) :

```
'Dim iStream As System.IO.Stream
    '' Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
    'Dim buffer(10000) As Byte
    '' Length of the file:
    'Dim length As Integer
    '' Total bytes to read:
    'Dim dataToRead As Long

    'Try
    '    ' Open the file.
    '    iStream = New System.IO.FileStream(pZipPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)

    '    ' Total bytes to read:
    '    dataToRead = iStream.Length

    '    pResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    '    pResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & Path.GetFileName(pZipPath))

    '    ' Read the bytes.
    '    While dataToRead > 0
    '        ' Verify that the client is connected.
    '        If pResponse.IsClientConnected Then
    '            ' Read the data in buffer
    '            length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000)

    '            ' Write the data to the current output stream.
    '            pResponse.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)

    '            ' Flush the data to the HTML output.
    '            pResponse.Flush()


    '            ReDim buffer(10000) ' Clear the buffer
    '            dataToRead = dataToRead - length
    '        Else
    '            'prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
    '            dataToRead = -1
    '        End If
    '    End While

    'Catch ex As Exception

    'Finally

    '    If IsNothing(iStream) = False Then
    '        ' Close the file.
    '        iStream.Close()
    '    End If
    '    pResponse.Close()
    'End Try
```

Comment: what does Chrome do? Do it just save the file automatically to a folder?

Comment: yep.  automatically to the downloads folder.

Comment: Won't you have the same problem if users configure Chrome to prompt before downloading the file? Meaning it's not browser specific, it's however the user has their browser configured.

Comment: just tested it and nope.  It does not have the same problem as IE.  It handles asking where to download it just fine and it opens just fine.

Comment: yea, that's what I'd expect Chrome and IE to do...prompt, then continue downloading. It must be something with the way you're sending the file. Can you post any code?

Comment: Yerp.  This was the 2nd go for trying to get it to work.

Comment: I read that link. Is the file you're downloading so large that you're trying this recommended solution...sending it in chunks instead of just the entire file?

Comment: the zip file sizes can vary from a few files to several hundred and can range from pdf to doc to excel.  It is possible I guess.

Comment: But you're downloading just zip files, right? What they contain is irrelevant. Are any zip files > 100MB? I'm only asking because I wouldn't do that recommended "Large File" workaround if they're not. I'd just send the entire file, not in chunks.